# @NotNull : validation custom message not displaying

Tags: java, validation, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA for creating application. In that I am trying to implement server side validation using annotation. I added `@NotNull` annotation on filed with custom message. I also added `@valid` with `@RequestBody`

But problem is that when I am passing `nAccountId` as `null` I am not getting custom message i.e. `Account id can not be null` I am getting "message": `"Validation failed for object='accountMaintenanceSave'. Error count: 1",`.

Can any one please tell me why I am not getting custom message?

**Controller code**

```
@PutMapping("/updateAccountData")
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveData(@Valid @RequestBody AccountMaintenanceSave saveObj){
    return accService.saveData(saveObj);
}
```

**AccountMaintenanceSave class**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class AccountMaintenanceSave {   

    @NotNull(message="Account id can not be null")
    public Integer nAccountId;
    @NotNull
    public String sClientAcctId;
    @NotNull
    public String sAcctDesc;
    @NotNull
    public String sLocation;
    @NotNull
    public Integer nDeptId; 
    @NotNull
    public Integer nAccountCPCMappingid;
    @NotNull
    public Integer nInvestigatorId;

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

**RestExceptionHandler class**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler { 

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex, WebRequest requset) {

        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

        exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

        // return exceptionMessageObj;
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I don't know what exactly happen previously and not getting proper message. Now using same code getting result like this with proper message

```
{
  "message": "Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.spacestudy.controller.AccountController.saveData(com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'accountMaintenanceSave' on field 'nAccountId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.accountMaintenanceSave.nAccountId,NotNull.nAccountId,NotNull.java.lang.Integer,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [accountMaintenanceSave.nAccountId,nAccountId]; arguments []; default message [nAccountId]]; default message [Account id can not be null]] ",
  "error": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "path": "/spacestudy/rockefeller/admin/account/updateAccountData"
}
```

In `message` filed can I print only  `[Account id can not be null]`?

Comment: Can you provide your ExceptionHandler class? I use the same annotation `@NotNull` and it is perfectly working for me

Comment: I added ExceptionHandler class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler { 

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex, WebRequest requset) {

    ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

    // Handle All Field Validation Errors
    if(ex instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = ((MethodArgumentNotValidException) ex).getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
        for(FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors){
            sb.append(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            sb.append(";");
        }
        exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(sb.toString());
    }else{
        exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

    // return exceptionMessageObj;
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to handle all types of exception with one method

Comment: @SpringUser I have updated my answer. This will give you the required output

Comment: you can define other custom exceptions in your @ControllerAdvice  marked class. All other exceptions not captured would be handled by the handleAllExceptionMethod including those of Validation

Answer (score 2):

It's not so good to make your **only** ExceptionHandler to catch Exception.class make it ConstraintViolationException.class

Answer (score 1):

> Another approach to the solution:

I would suggest remove the `exception handler` for this validation fields in the `POJO` and rather let `Spring` handle the error response by adding the below property into application.properties. By adding this the message configured in the `@notnull` or any validation annotation can be captured and showed in the response by default and no `explicit handling` of this validation case is required.

```
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```