# Custom error message on enum field upon failed validation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, enums

I have an enum field in my Spring DTO which I use in my `@RestController`. I wish to create custom error message upon failed validation for this enum field:

```
public class ConversionInputDto {

    // validation annotations
    private BigDecimal sourceAmount;

    // enum field
    @NotNull(message = ERROR_EMPTY_VALUE)
    private CurrencyFormat targetCurrency;

    // no-args constructor and getters
}
```

Receiving input as a String and making a [custom annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070806/11812518) seems an overkill in my case, and the other alternative, which I know, catches all `InvalidFormatException` errors via `@ControllerAdvise` and returns the same error for them (thus, a user submitting e.g. String input for numeric property will get the same error message):

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
public void handleInvalidEnumAndAllOtherInvalidConversions(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

The current default validation error is too long and I would like to make it more user-friendly like *"Invalid currency format value. Please choose between...."*:

> "Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type
>   `com.foreignexchange.utilities.CurrencyFormat` from String \"test\":
>   not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [AUD, PLN, MXN, USD,
>   CAD]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type
>   `com.foreignexchange.utilities.CurrencyFormat` from String \"test\":
>   not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [AUD, PLN, MXN, USD,
>   CAD]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 20]
>   (through reference chain:
>   com.foreignexchange.models.ConversionInputDto[\"targetCurrency\"])",

Is there an elegant way to solve this? Perhaps with some additional logic in the `@ExceptionHandler` checking which field has failed validation?

Comment: You might try [registering a custom deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for your enum class that would throw a custom exception with a more user-friendly message

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386294/notnull-validation-custom-message-not-displaying?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I was hoping to avoid instanceOf checks, but it is the shortest way I could find. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the comments, I found a solution by using `isAssignableFrom()` to provide custom error messages for the failed enum validation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
public void handleOfflineBankApi(HttpServletResponse response, InvalidFormatException ex) throws IOException {
    if (ex.getTargetType().isAssignableFrom(CurrencyFormat.class)) {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), Constants.ERROR_INVALID_CURRENCY_FORMAT);
    } else {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```